# What do you call a definable set where the parameters are constrained to be unique?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Is **fixability** (like definability but with the parameters constrained to be unique) a real notion?

What is it actually called?

Does it appear anywhere besides the definition of elimination of imaginaries?

---

NCatLab's definition of [elimination of imaginaries](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/elimination+of+imaginaries#definition) is given below. I'm making a small adjustment to the definition because a theory $T$ has elimination of imaginaries if and only if all of its models do.

> <strike>*T*</strike> [$M$] has elimination of imaginaries if [and only if] for every definable set $X = \{m \in \mathbb{M} \mathop| \varphi(m, b)\}$, there exists a formula $\psi(x, y)$ and a tuple $c$ with the same sort as $y$ such that $c$ uniquely satisfies $X = \{ m \in \mathbb{M} \mathop| \psi(m, c) \}$.

In the above definition, $m$, $b$, $c$, $x$, and $y$ are all implicitly tuples or perhaps maps from variable names to domain elements. Additionally, $M$ is a first-order structure and $\mathbb{M}$ is the set of tuples of some length determined by the context over the domain of $M$. The distinction between $M$ and $\mathbb{M}$ is not present in the original definition, but I'm thinking about the NCatLab notation in this way to keep track of which things are tuples and which things are not.

I'm familiar with what a definable set is; it's the set corresponding to a formula $\varphi(\cdots)$ with parameters.

However, it seems to me that we can introduce a notion of a **fixable** set (I'm making this word up) and make the above definition much shorter.

> Let a set $X$ be **fixable** if and only if there exists a formula $\alpha(x, y)$ such that there exists a unique $c$ such that $X$ is equal to $\{ m \in \mathbb{M} \mathop| \alpha(m, c) \}$.

In which case NCatLab's definition would simplify to:

> $M$ has elimination of imaginaries if and only if every definable set over $M$ is fixable in $M$.

Intuitively, fixability seems to occupy a *middle rung* on the ladder *0-definable*, *fixable*, *definable*. However, it also seems like the fixable sets of a given dimension need not form a nice lattice like the definable and 0-definable sets do.

Comment: That is a funny definition of EI. Your definition of "fixable" basically says that $X$ is interdefinable with a real tuple. Which is closer to the more standard definiton of EI, namely that every imaginary is interdefinable with a real tuple.

Comment: A more general variant of this would be if you consider a multi-sorted structure, then you could consider elements in a sort which are interdefinable with elements in some other sort(s). To see that this is a special case, consider $X$ as an element of $M^{\mathrm{eq}}$. I'm not sure if this notion was considered in depth in this generality, besides some special cases like valued fields.

Comment: @tomasz Just to clarify, is it NCatLab's definition of EI that's unusual or my paraphrase of it? Does NCatLab's definition line up with the more standard one if you look at whole theories at a time instead of individual structures?

Comment: Mostly the ncatlab definition. I'm not saying the definition is *wrong*. I'm pretty sure it's equivalent to the usual one, I just find the phrasing a bit funny. Then again, that is a given for ncatlab, I guess. :) As for your variant of the definition for models, I don't think I've seen it before, but it seems reasonable (well, still a bit odd in the same sense). I have a feeling that it is likely to be equivalent to EI for the theory of $M$, but I did not think about it too much.